# Sound wont transmit to Epson Projector

Tags: mojave, projector

I have an Epson projector in my school that can receive both audio and video transmitted from machines running El Capitan, but cannot receive audio from Machines running High Sierra or Mojave (but video works, just not audio). I have downloaded the latest driver from Epson, but it still doesn't work.  Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: This is a bit broad...First, make and model of Epson projector.   What are the differences in Macs running the different OSes?  Do the Macs that don't work with that projector, work elsewhere?

Comment: does the Epson Audio shows in Audio devices output ? are you using USB cable or Wireless ?

Comment: Hi, yes, and in fact, when the macbook is connected o the projector, sound stops playing on the local computer and the volume controls are disabled (which is expected) so it is as if the macbook knows to send sound to the projector, but for whatever reason, the projector does not play it.

Comment: The exact same setup, on an identical macbook running El Capitan works as expected.  High Sierra and mojave macbooks cannot play their sound through the projector.